# Hide Port Number From URL

Tags: apache, webserver, wamp, port, wampserver

I'm having trouble with my website that when a user types my url they have to type a port number which is 16000. My router is unable to forward port 80 because it is used by ISP itself. So basically my question is am I able to make port dissapear from my url while it being on port 16000.

Comment: Try using port 443 (https) or find another ISP.

Comment: `http` defaults to port 80.  It's a **standard**.  There is no reliable way to do this in-house, if your ISP doesn't allow port 80 to even come through ...  You should be looking into hosting somewhere else.  There are plenty of free, or near-free hosts out there ..

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot hide **"16000" port number** from your url.

Because:

- For **"http" url**, browser can only hide **"80" port number**.
- For **"https" url**, browser can only hide **"443" port number**.

Answer (score -1):

are you asking how to set up a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)?

Comment: Did you seriously answer a question with a question?

Comment: I did, and I wouldn't ANSWER clarifying what his is ASKING about .. I'd COMMENT ..